# PHP if() not working as designed?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a little bit confusing on why this won't work. I can do a work around, but any ideas? It's to match an uploaded CSV to a configuration in a database. Returns only the first 5 columns. The rest, user specified ones (should print Echo) do not show up.

> $csv_col while looping = 
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
>
> $getConfiguration[0] =
>
> Array
>   (
>       [config_key] => 22
>       [config_client_ident] => 105
>       [config_s_timestamp] => 1378008000
>       [config_e_timestamp] => 
>       [config_kpi_1] => 81
>       [config_kpi_2] => 82
>       [config_kpi_3] => 83
>       [config_kpi_4] => 84
>       [config_kpi_5] => 
>       [config_kpi_6] => 
>       [config_kpi_7] => 
>       [config_kpi_8] => 
>       [config_kpi_9] => 
>       [config_kpi_10] => 
>       [config_kpi_11] => 
>       [config_kpi_12] => 
>       [config_kpi_13] => 
>       [config_kpi_14] => 
>       [config_kpi_15] => 
>       [config_kpi_16] => 
>       [config_kpi_17] => 
>       [config_kpi_18] => 
>       [config_kpi_19] => 
>       [config_kpi_20] => 
>       [config_kpi_21] => 
>       [config_kpi_22] => 
>       [config_kpi_23] => 
>       [config_kpi_24] => 
>       [config_kpi_25] => 
>       [config_kpi_26] => 
>       [config_kpi_27] => 
>       [config_kpi_28] => 
>       [config_kpi_29] => 
>       [config_kpi_30] => 
>       [config_kpi_31] => 
>       [config_kpi_32] => 
>       [config_kpi_33] => 
>       [config_kpi_34] => 
>       [config_kpi_35] => 
>       [config_kpi_36] => 
>       [config_kpi_37] => 
>       [config_kpi_38] => 
>       [config_kpi_39] => 
>       [config_kpi_40] => 
>       [config_kpi_41] => 
>       [config_kpi_42] => 
>       [config_kpi_43] => 
>       [config_kpi_44] => 
>       [config_kpi_45] => 
>       [config_kpi_46] => 
>       [config_kpi_47] => 
>       [config_kpi_48] => 
>       [config_kpi_49] => 
>       [config_kpi_50] => 
>   )
>
> $csvRead[0]
>
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Data Date
>       [1] => Agent IDENT
>       [2] => Client IDENT
>       [3] => Location IDENT
>       [4] => Program IDENT
>       [5] => xx VSAT
>       [6] => xx SWSAT
>       [7] => xx NSODS
>       [8] => xx SWDSAT
>   )
>
> Returned from query
>
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [key_id] => 84
>               [key_enabled] => 1
>               [key_name] => xx SWDSAT
>               [key_desc] => xx CSAT Somewhat Dissatisfied
>           )

)

```
// Build the check arary
    $checkArray = array("Data Date", "Agent IDENT", "Client IDENT", "Location IDENT", "Program IDENT");
    $fileVerification = true;
    $config_col = 1;

    // Loop through the 50 available columns
    while($config_col <= 50){
        $csv_col = $config_col - 1;
        print $csv_col . " ";
        // Make sure something is in those columns
        if($getConfiguration[0]['config_kpi_'.$config_col] != ''){
            // There is, now lets query and get those names.
            $getNamesQuery[] = "SELECT * FROM kpi_keys WHERE key_id=".$getConfiguration[0]['config_kpi_'.$config_col];
            $getNamesResult = dbInsert($getNamesQuery);
            // Compare the first 5 columns
            if($csv_col < 5){
                if($csvRead[0][$csv_col] == $checkArray[$csv_col]){
                    $output .= '<div class="messageGood"> - '.$csvRead[0][$csv_col].' column verified.</div>';
                } else {
                    $output .= '<div class="messageBad"> - Column "'.$csvRead[0][$csv_col].'" did not match "'.$checkArray[$csv_col].'" in the current configuration.</div>';
                    $fileVerification = false;
                }
            } else {
                // Now lets compare the customizable columns. We're going to do names and ID's to make sure.
                print "Echo";
            }
            $getNamesQuery = null;
        }
        $config_col++;
    }

    // Now we check the information

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($getConfiguration[0]);
    print_r($csvRead[0]);
    print_r($getNamesResult);
    print "</pre>";
```

> Answer (Thanks Wrikken)

```
// Loop through the 50 available columns
    while($config_col <= 50){
        $csv_col = $config_col - 1;
        $partOne = '';
        $partTwo = '';
        // Make sure something is in those columns
        // Compare the first 5 columns
        if($csv_col < 5){
            if($csvRead[0][$csv_col] == $checkArray[$csv_col]){
                $partOne .= '<div class="messageGood"> - '.$csvRead[0][$csv_col].' column verified.</div>';
            } else {
                $partOne .= '<div class="messageBad"> - Column "'.$csvRead[0][$csv_col].'" did not match "'.$checkArray[$csv_col].'" in the current configuration.</div>';
                $fileVerification = false;
            }
        }
        if($getConfiguration[0]['config_kpi_'.$config_col] != ''){
            print $csv_col . " ";
            // There is, now lets query and get those names.
            $getNamesQuery[] = "SELECT * FROM kpi_keys WHERE key_id=".$getConfiguration[0]['config_kpi_'.$config_col];
            $getNamesResult = dbInsert($getNamesQuery);
            // Now lets compare the customizable columns. We're going to do names and ID's to make sure.
            $partTwo = "Comparison";
            $getNamesQuery = null;
        }
        $config_col++;
    }
    $output .= $partOne . $partTwo;
```

Comment: You have many `if` statements in your code. Which one is not working as expected?

Comment: Be specific, and make a reproducible example.  I can guarantee you that `if` works fine, and the problem is your code.

Comment: have you `var_dump`ed the variables to see that what you are checking against is actually what you think they should be

Comment: What's in `$getConfiguration[0]`?

Comment: @FluffyMittensofDeath: And what is the value of `$csv_col` when this line of code "fails"?

Comment: @Wrikken
Array
(
    [config_key] => 22
    [config_client_ident] => 105
    [config_s_timestamp] => 1378008000
    [config_e_timestamp] => 
    [config_kpi_1] => 81
    [config_kpi_2] => 82
    [config_kpi_3] => 83
    [config_kpi_4] => 84
    [config_kpi_5] => ...
)

Comment: @Wrikken When $csv_col >= 4

Comment: @FluffyMittensofDeath: do you have `config_kpi_6`, `config_kpi_7` ... `config_kpi_50` in there, and if so, what are their values?

Comment: @AmalMurali if($csv_col < 5){}

Comment: @FluffyMittensofDeath: so, `if($getConfiguration[0]['config_kpi_'.$config_col] != ''){` prevents running the rest of the code...

Comment: @Wrikken

You're right. I knew I was tired today. Answer is that I need to while or do another loop. In this case it's imperative that I keep order between the two sources. Want to use that as an answer and I'll give you credit?

Comment: @Wrikken
Copy pasta edited in for your credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while($csv_col < 5){
                if($csvRead[0][$csv_col] == $checkArray[$csv_col]){
                    $output .= '<div class="messageGood"> - '.$csvRead[0][$csv_col].' column verified.</div>';
```

if only runs one time,if you want to concatenate use while, it will run..until the end.